# Set page sizes for Alphabetical Pagination gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I want to group post titles alphabetically, similar to https://rubygems.org/gems.

I was using the Alphabetical Pagination gem, which works fine, however, I got stuck when trying to set limits for each page.

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  
def index

@posts, @alphaParams = Post.all.alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:bootstrap3 =>"false", :numbers => "false", :paginate_all => "true"}){|post| post.title}

  end
end

  <div id="pagination_table">
  <%= alphabetical_paginate @alphaParams %>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h2><%= post.title.titleize %></h2>
  <p>
  <%= post.body.capitalize %>
  </p>
  <div>
  <% end%>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation for the gem you are using please?

Comment: @MaxWilliams https://github.com/lingz/alphabetical_paginate